# Power Raspberry Pi Pico from Mains (use LED driver?)

Tags: power-supply, usb, led-driver, raspberry-pi-pico

I'd like to permanently install a Raspberry Pi Pico in a place in my house where I don't have a power socket but a power line (230V, 50Hz).

As I understand it, there are [two](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/introduction-to-the-pico/12) [ways](https://howchoo.com/pi/how-to-power-the-raspberry-pi-pico/) to power the Pico:

1. using USB.
2. through the VSYS and a GND pin.

Number 1 would require installing a power socket so I can plug in a USB power supply.  This takes up much more space than necessary, in particular since the Pi is supposed to stay permanently. Alternatively, I could use a [power socket with USB connectors](https://www.amazon.de/UCOMEN-Steckdosen-Anschl%C3%BCssen-Electrical-Unterputzdose%EF%BC%8Cwei%C3%9F/dp/B088BJJFGY/ref=sr_1_59?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=ZZ67EOG9VYWK&keywords=USB%2BSteckdose&qid=1702462594&sprefix=usb%2Bsteckdose%2Caps%2C98&sr=8-59&th=1), but they're still bulkier than they need to be, and not really intended for this kind of application.

I'd prefer Number 2, but I'm unsure what kind of power supply to use.  I found a [power supply](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B07C53B1GZ?ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details&th=1) for Pis and Pi-like MCs that connects to regular mains, but it says it must be installed on a breadboard, which would require connecting the mains to a breadboard which doesn't seem very robust.  I haven't found any power supplies that are meant for MCs and can be connected to mains cables permanently.

I have found [LED drivers](https://www.amazon.de/LPV-60-5-LED-Schaltnetzteil-40W-IP67-Class2/dp/B072LSCFJS/ref=sr_1_15?keywords=LED%2Bdriver%2B5v&qid=1702462323&sr=8-15&th=1) that convert from 230V to 5V, but I'm not sure whether something like that would fry my Pi.

**So, questions:**

1. Am I missing any other options?
2. What are reasons for and against the options mentioned that I'm missing?
3. In particular, are LED drivers a good solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some LED drivers are constant current (and vary the voltage to maintain it). You don't want that, although the one you linked appears to be constant voltage so may be OK.

The usual device to use is a power supply with screw terminals, like [this one](https://cpc.farnell.com/tiger-power-supplies/tgr15-5/industrial-enclosed-power-supply/dp/PW04919) from CPC in the UK. They have a pair of terminals for the 230V input and another pair for the 5V output (they also exist in other voltages, e.g. 12V, and current ratings). You will want an appropriate enclosure to put it inside too. Depending on the enclosure for your project there are also [versions which mount on DIN rails](https://cpc.farnell.com/mean-well/hdr-30-5/power-supply-ac-dc-5v-3a/dp/PW04670).

I would avoid the power supplies with pins on the bottom unless you are designing a custom PCB to mount them on (which requires special consideration for trace separation and input protection - with the screw terminal power supplies that's all handled for you).

Comment: Awesome, thank you, the constant voltage/constant current distinction was something that I hadn't paid attention to!